# How to specify type of a React class component with static props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Consider we have a simple React component with a **static property** like `meta` here:

```js
// RectTool.tsx

class Rect extends React.PureComponent
    static meta = {
        icon: <AnotherComponent />,
        initial: {
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
        },
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>Hello World</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then in another component we're referencing that component as a prop:

```js
// DesignerUI.tsx

<Designer
    tools={[Rect]}
/>
```

How do we define the type for the `tools` prop in `<Designer />` so that typescript would be
happy. What I'm doing right now is:

```js
// DesignerUI.tsx

interface Props {
  tools: Array<
    React.PureComponent & {
      meta: {
        icon: JSX.Element;
        initial: { width: number; height: number; strokeWidth: number };
      };
    }
  >;
}
```

And typescript gives me this error:

```
Type 'typeof Rect' is not assignable to type 'PureComponent<{}, {}, any> & { meta: { icon: Element; initial: { width: number; height: number; strokeWidth: number; }; }; }'.
  Type 'typeof Rect' is missing the following properties from type 'PureComponent<{}, {}, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 3 more.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason that a tool needs to be a `React.PureComponent` specifically.  It seems like your requirements for your tool objects should be:

1. It can be called using JSX as `<Rect/>` with no props.
2. It has a `meta` property with the appropriate values.

I would suggest that you define the type for your `ToolMeta` at the top level and use it in both the `Rect` and the `Designer`.  You've already got a mismatch between `initialValues` in one place and `initial` in another.  A good `ToolMeta` type can prevent this sort of mistake.

Personally I prefer to keep most interfaces one-level deep and break out sub-properties into their own named types.

```
interface ToolInitialValues {
    width: number;
    height: number;
    strokeWidth?: number;
}

interface ToolMeta {
    icon: JSX.Element;
    initialValues: ToolInitialValues;
}
```

We can use this type in the `Rect` to get type-checking on the `meta` object:

```
class Rect extends React.PureComponent {
    static meta: ToolMeta = {
```

Your tool components must have `{ meta: ToolMeta }` to meet condition #2.  For condition #1, you'll want to use the `React.ComponentType` type which is the type for a function component or class component.  Your current `React.PureComponent` type actually refers to the *instance* rather than the *class* itself.

```
interface Props {
  tools: Array<
    React.ComponentType & { meta: ToolMeta }
  >;
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wXz0Vm)

Comment: Thanks Linda. The type mismatch for initial and initialValue was a typo and I edited the original post.